# How to implement rotation system for an AVL tree using vector implementation C++

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search-tree, stdvector, avl-tree

I have to make an AVL tree, and am using a vector notation for efficiency. I have completed a binary search tree, but I am having issues trying to figure out how to implement balancing system.

I have researched online but all solutions assume a node object implementation. In my current BST I have a vector, with the value at index 0 being 0, and then the BST starting, with the left node being 2*i, and the right node being 2*i+1.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can give some tips on how to convert this BST to an AVL tree.

Comment: Can you show what you’ve tried and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not sure how to start, so I have no code for the AVL part, but did you want me to share the code for my binary tree?